# Calling AsyncTask class it does not execute doInBackgound method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

when calling

> new AsyncFeed(strurl).execute();

after this its able to call constructor of AsyncFeed but not able to execute doInBackground(). while debugging i found out it calls constructor and then simply returns back to the calling statement making a nullpointer exception in later code

```
public class HttpHandler {
    public HttpHandler() {
    }
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer;
    String strurl;

    public String getJsonString(String strurl){
        new AsyncFeed(strurl).execute();
        return String.valueOf(stringBuffer);
    }

class AsyncFeed extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    String urlStr;
    public AsyncFeed(String urlStr) {
        this.urlStr=urlStr;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(bufferedReader !=null)
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that `stringBuffer` is `null`, it's because function `public String getJsonString(String strurl)` returns `String` value of uninitialized `stringBuffer` before `AsyncFeed` is completed. You should use something like this:

```
public void loadJsonString(String strurl){
        new AsyncFeed(strurl).execute();
        //return String.valueOf(stringBuffer);
    }

class AsyncFeed extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    String urlStr;
    public AsyncFeed(String urlStr) {
        this.urlStr=urlStr;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... records) {
        try {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(bufferedReader !=null)
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        }

        return null;
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //f.e. show progress dialog
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //now you have initialized stringBuffer so do what you want with it

        //hide progress dialog

        //print String value of stringBuffer initialized in doInBackground
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(stringBuffer)); 
    }
)
```

There are more options to do that but it's hard to write exactly what you need without seeing more of your code or specify your question, so if you have some 
questions to me just write comment :) or read more here [Android Developers - AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**EDIT**

Okay I understand, try do it like this, the idea is just pass calling object into the async task and from there in onPostExecute() will be updated data 
in ClassA and continue with what you need

```
public class ClassA{
    String url;
    String jsonObjectString;

    //instead of getJsonString(url) call this and after async task will finish
    //it calls updateDataFromAsync() so you will have data loaded and you can continue work with it in doSomethingAfterAsync()
    private void loadData(){
        //pass the calling object into the async task
        new HttpHandler(this).startLoadJsonString(url);
    }

    //this will async taks call in onPostExecute()
    public void updateDataFromAsync(String s){
        jsonObjectString = s;
        doSomethingAfterAsync();
    }    

    private doSomethingAfterAsync(){

    }
}

public class HttpHandler {

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer;
    String strurl;
    ClassA classA;

     public HttpHandler(ClassA classA) {
         this.classA = classA;
     } 

    public void startLoadJsonString(String strurl){
        new AsyncFeed(strurl).execute();
    }

    private class AsyncFeed extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        String urlStr;

        public AsyncFeed(String urlStr) {
            this.urlStr=urlStr;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... records) {
            try {
                url = new URL(urlStr);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(bufferedReader !=null)
                    try {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //f.e. show progress dialog
        }

         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //now you have initialized stringBuffer so do what you want with it

            //hide progress dialog

            //call updateDataFromAsync from ClassA class and continue there
            classA.updateDataFromAsync(String.valueOf(stringBuffer));
        }
    )
```

Comment: i'm calling this method from different class 
 jsonObjectString =new HttpHandler().getJsonString(url);
what i wanted to say is i need to get string from Asynctask and return it from the method which calls the AsyncTask , but by the time the doInBackground does its work , the getJsonString returns A null String.

Comment: this looks perfect , haven't implemented it yet, but looks this will give my ans , i'll give you feedback after executing. thanks :)

Comment: Good luck! I'll be grateful for your feedback :)